React Mediaplayer not working when i try to implement a video -
I have been trying to insert a video in my react video component but I can't figure out what's wrong. I have been trying different solutions but I can't seem to find the problem (I'm still new a programmering)
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const setPlaybackRate = (rate: number) => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current.playbackRate = rate;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlaybackRate(2);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="player-wrapper">
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        controls
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        loop 
        autoPlay
        muted  
      >
        <source src="./video/SkillsVideo2.mov" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;


I imported the video file at the top of the component file to ensure it's correctly referenced and accessible within the component.
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import myvid from "./assets/video-1@c.mp4";

const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const setPlaybackRate = (rate: number) => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current.playbackRate = rate;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlaybackRate(2);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="player-wrapper">
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        controls
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        loop
        autoPlay
        muted
      >
        <source src={myvid} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;

since you are using ts you are going to run into a declaration problem so you have to declare the types of your files and to do this your going to have to do this

create a globle.d.ts file in your project folder
declare the type like this

    /* globle.d.ts */
    declare module "*.jpg" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
    }


you have to mention this file in your tsconfig.json

   /* tsconfig.json */
   "include": ["src" , "globle.d.ts"],

